# Resize image buttons using mipmaps android

Tags: android, android-imagebutton, mipmaps

There are 8 `imgbutton`s on my activity. I want them to resize for different screens, but they stay the same. I am using `mipmaps`.

Main.xml:

......

```
 <ImageButton
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@mipmap/adduser2"  
    android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
    android:background="#ffffffff"
    android:layout_margin="33dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
    android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
    android:background="#ffffffff"
    android:layout_margin="33dp"
  />
```

manifest:

```
  <supports-screens 
     android:resizeable="true"
     android:smallScreens="true"
     android:normalScreens="true"
     android:largeScreens="true"
     android:xlargeScreens="true"
     android:anyDensity="true"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

[This Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) should give you the answer, you need to create different images and put them in their respective folders based on their `pixel densities`.

Comment: I did that. I have different sizes images in folders